# What is the best Regex pattern in C# to ignore some group of characters like (*SKIP)(*F) in perl?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex expression:

```
(?:\\\\u|\\\\U)(*SKIP)(*F)|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8}
```

It works well in **`Perl`**. Test result:

[image]

But `(*SKIP)` and `(*F)` dose not work in `C#` and i need a regex with above behavior in `C#`.

What is best (easiest) way in `c#` Regex to ignore some group of characters?

Comment: Note that in `\\\u0021` the preceding slashes don't escape the one in `\u0021`, they only figure a literal slash.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, yes i just want sure that the pattern ignore each sentence with more than 1 slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind in `C#` instead of PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)`:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8})
```

[RegEx Demo 1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5C%5C)(%3F%3A%5C%5Cu%5B0-9a-fA-F%5D%7B4%7D%7C%5C%5CU%5B0-9a-fA-F%5D%7B8%7D)&i=%5Cu0021%0D%0A%5C%5Cu0021%0D%0A%5C%5C%5Cu0021%0D%0A%5C%5C%5C%5Cu0021)

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/2JjwPA/1)

`(?<!\\)` is negative lookbehind, that will fail the match if we have a backslash before `\u` or `\U`.

Comment: Your answer was so fast! Thank you.